# Halt rest of viewDidLoad while other class fetches data

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In one of my view controllers I am setting a label based on the "GET" data I receive from a separate `NSObject` class. Obviously it takes much less time to set the label then it does to fetch the data so the label is always set to nil. How can I insure the label isn't set till the data is done fetching.

This is the method preforming the "getting" in the `NSObject` class `myClass`

```
- (void) doGetURL:(NSString *) urlstring
callBackTarget:(id) target
callBackMethod:(NSString *) method
 failedMethod:(NSString *) method_failed
 {

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]];
NSLog(@"-- get URL with cookie : [%@] and hash:(%@)", [self cookie], [self modhash]);
if (cookie && [cookie length] > 0)
{
    NSDictionary *properties = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                cookieDomain, NSHTTPCookieDomain,
                                @"/", NSHTTPCookiePath, 
                                @"reddit_session", NSHTTPCookieName,
                                cookie, NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                //                                      [cookie stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], NSHTTPCookieValue,
                                nil];
    NSHTTPCookie *http_cookie = [NSHTTPCookie cookieWithProperties:properties];
    NSArray* cookies = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: http_cookie, nil];
    NSDictionary * headers = [NSHTTPCookie requestHeaderFieldsWithCookies:cookies];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
}
NSURLConnection * connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

NSString *connectionKey = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", ((intptr_t) connection)];
NSMutableDictionary *dl = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[dl setValue:connectionKey forKey:@"connectionKey"];
if (target && method)
{
    [dl setValue:target forKey:@"afterCompleteTarget"];
    [dl setValue:method forKey:@"afterCompleteAction"];
}
[dl setValue:method_failed forKey:@"failedNotifyAction"];
[connections setValue:dl forKey:connectionKey];
}
```

That is being called in another method within `myClass`

```
- (void)getUserInfo:(NSString*)user
{
NSString *getString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user/%@/about.json",server,user];

[self doGetURL:getString callBackTarget:self callBackMethod:@"userInfoResponse:" failedMethod:@"connectionFailedDialog:"];
}
```

The call back method:

```
- (void)userInfoResponse:(id)sender
{    
NSLog(@"userInfoResponse in()");
NSData * data = (NSData *) sender;
NSError *error;

NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:data

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];

NSDictionary *response = [json objectForKey:@"data"];

//futureLabelStr is a property of myClass
futureLabelStr = [response objectForKey:@"name"];;

}
```

then the label is set in the View Controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[myClass getUserInfo:@"some_user"];

myLabel.txt = myClass.futureLabelStr;

}
```

Please let me know is I need to add more or anything I tried to organize it as best I could but I might have missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to "halt" your viewController's viewDidLoad, you want to notify it, when
the information changes.

You could do that by either sending a notification when myClass is done and `-userInfoResponse:` is called (Look at NSNotificationCenter), or implement a delegate pattern in myClass. You could set your viewController as a delegate for myClass and call a delegate method when myClass is finished fetching on viewController that would itself update the label.

Or, looking at your code, you could set your viewController as the receiver of the callback methods with minimal change to your code, even though that is **not the best approach** because it violates MVC patterns:

```
[self doGetURL:getString callBackTarget:viewController callBackMethod:@"userInfoResponse:" failedMethod:@"connectionFailedDialog:"];
```

You would of course need a reference to viewController in myClass and the viewController would need to implement this methods (which is a MVC pattern violation).

Answer (score 0):

Send the data call on a new thread and finish viewDidLoad as normal. Then use NSNotification center from whoever is fetching this (should be a model) to the viewController saying "hey, I got that label for you, come get it and refresh"

Then the VC will just set the label using the data from the model.  Check out this link for using NSNotificationCenter stackoverflow.com/questions/2191594/send-and-receive-messages-through-nsnotificationcenter-in-objective-c.

For multithreading read up on grand central dispatch.